# How would one implement `localStorage.setItem` with the semantics of `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent`?

Tags: javascript, concurrency, local-storage

The standard `localStorage` does not support anything that would allow setting a key value with the same semantics as `computeIfAbsent` in, for example, Java's `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Getting a key value first to check if it exists, and then setting a value for that key, if it does not exist, is not an atomic operation. This makes the use of `localStorage` from different browser tabs/windows challenging, if one needs to ensure that a key value can be assigned only once.

If you had a similar need, how would you solve this?

Comment: Have you considered using IndexedDB instead? (Or some library that runs on top of IndexedDB.) `localStorage` was designed just for the simplest use cases — and when trying to use it for more than that, you generally start pretty quickly running into a variety of limitations.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, we have not, so thank you for that idea. It should indeed be possible to utilise a unique index to ensure that only one entry exists. Will develop a spike to see if the use of IndexDB fits some of our other criteria, and will get back to you.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, thank you once again for your suggestion. It worked well for our needs. Please post it as an answer and I would be glad to accept it.